# Polymorphism and Constructors

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am an AP Java Student and I am practicing for my exam.  I came across this question and I don't understand the answer:

Consider the following classes:

```
public class A
{
  public A() { methodOne(); }

  public void methodOne() { System.out.print("A"); }
}

public class B extends A
{
  public B() { System.out.print("*"); }

  public void methodOne() { System.out.print("B"); }
}
```

What is the output when the following code is executed:

```
A obj = new B();
```

The correct answer is B*.  Can someone please explain to me the sequence of method calls?

Comment: Add a print statement to the constructor of `A`, and it may become clearer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The B constructor is called. The first implicit instruction of the B constructor is `super()` (call the default constructor of super class). So A's constructor is called. A's constructor calls `super()`, which invokes the java.lang.Object constructor, which doesn't print anything. Then `methodOne()` is called. Since the object is of type B, the B's version of `methodOne` is called, and `B` is printed. Then the B constructor continues executing, and `*` is printed.

It must be noted that calling an overridable method from a constructor (like A's constructor  does) is very bad practice: it calls a method on an object which is not constructed yet.

Comment: And, the overidden method may not work the way `Class A` expects it to.

Answer (score 2):

The base class must be constructed before the derived class.

First `A()` is called which calls `methodOne()` which prints `B`.

Next, `B()` is called which prints `*`.